# table using div cell height issue (with angular)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm having an issue with cell height on my table. I tried putting min-height of 115px sort of work for certain number of languages but if its more than it breaks the cell. I need the cell to expand no matter how many languages there are in the cell.

```
.comparison-table .lang{
  min-height: 115px;
  height: 100%/auto;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please add more information. This is not enough. Even a snippet of functioning code.

Comment: a JS fiddle would be really helpful here

Comment: Screenshot shows quite a few elements. Help us help you by posting HTML and CSS for these elements. And, as @zedd pointed out, a place to fiddle with your code would help a ton, too. :-)

Comment: The problem at the moment is that the data is being pulled using angular from the backend. The data is being rendered by column rather than row, so each divs as no relation to each other which is making the css a little harder :/. Jquery/Js solution for dynamic height maybe?

Comment: Jquery/Js solution for dynamic height is easy to do but would be wrong in the senses of practicality. What you would want is to either split the header with the rest of the body (and add a break) or make the table, work like a table. If you have to use JS, then add a class to the the top row for each object. Then have JS to find what one has the max hight. Then set them all to that height. I would not do this though.

Comment: @Scor3keeper Yeah that's how the structure is like, the header is separated from the body. its something like this http://jsfiddle.net/z5z6govg/

Comment: @Scor3keeper can you show me how to do it using jquery though.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what was asked above.

Even though I do not agree with this, here is the how to add a class to the the top row for each object. Then have JS to find what one has the max hight. Then set them all to that height.

HTML

```
<div class="test" style="height:40px; width:20px; background-color:red;"></div>
<div class="test" style="height:60px; width:20px; background-color:blue;"></div>
<div class="test" style="height:80px; width:20px; background-color:green;"></div>
<div class="test" style="height:90px; width:20px; background-color:yellow;"></div>
```

JS

```
var maxHeight = 0;
$( ".test" ).each(function( index ) {     
    if ( $( this ).height() > maxHeight ){
     maxHeight = $( this ).height();
    }
});

$('.test').css({"height": maxHeight});
```

[Code Preview](http://jsfiddle.net/tjedLas3/)